# Udemy multiple monitor issue while connecting through docking station

Tags: video-streaming, multiple-monitors

I am using multiple monitors connected through a docking station. When I am using Udemy, the external monitor gets disconnected whenever it navigates to the next video after it completes playing the current video.

I have to unplug-plug again the docking station to reconnect to the external monitor again.

Any solution for this problem?

Comment: Hi did you get a fix for the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

set monitor refresh rate(s) to 60hz :)
got blackscreens at video start cuz my external monitor was at 75hz

Comment: Did the same but did not fix the problem

Comment: I can confirm this does not work for me either i already have tried 59.95hz or 60.01hz.

Answer (score 0):

this solution worked for me :

settings -> search for hardware acceleration -> disable

Comment: I did the same thing but my display's still get disconnected. Right now i am having an acer swift 3 core with an intel 8th gen cpu and having two P2419H dell monitors attached to my system. OS : windows 11 home. I am facing the same problems when it comes to netflix as well as other apps. any other fix would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was using two monitors with my docking station, which has two HDMI ports. One of the monitors (a Dell monitor) was turning off whenever I was playing Udemy videos.

I tried disabling hardware acceleration in the settings, but this didn't work for me.

To resolve the issue, I connected an HDMI cable directly to my laptop's HDMI port instead of using the docking station's HDMI port. The other monitor was still connected to the docking station's HDMI port."